# HTTP Error 401.2 - Unauthorized You are not authorized to view this page due to invalid authentication headers

Tags: iis-7.5, http-status-code-401, basic-authentication, unauthorizedaccessexcepti

i want to allow access to `Anonymous.aspx` page to all user,
i have set **Basic Authentication to Enabled**, and **Connect as to specific user**.

my problem is when trying to access `http://MyIPAddress/MyAlias/Anonymous.aspx`, authentication popup appears--ideally it shouldn't, and when i close popup, getting `401.2 Unauthorized error`--it's obvious

Error Summary

*HTTP Error 401.2 - Unauthorized 
You are not authorized to view this page due to invalid authentication headers. 
Error Code  0x80070005*

below is snap of my web.config file.

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
       <authentication mode=“Windows“/>
   </system.web>

   <location path=“Anonymous.aspx“>
       <system.web>
          <authorization>
              <allow users=“*“/>
          </authorization>
       </system.web>
   </location>
 </configuration>
```

how can i solve this error.

Comment: Old question, but: if an authentication popup appears, it's most likely due to directory permissions set in the file system.

Answer (score 45):

Make sure Anonymous access is enabled on IIS -> Authentication.

But also right click on it, then click on Edit, and choose a domain\username and password. (With access to the physical folder of the application).

Comment: Hi Rockster  , I applied your advise and double checked access all the users i tried have got full access to the physical drive. but i'm still getting the same error page. bare in mind Forms Authentication is also disabled, when i enable it i get a different type of error, is there a way to get around this? Thanks

Comment: Hi @Jawad, once you add/edit the user's security permissions of the website folder using Windows, make sure you also clic the "advanced" button inside the Security tab. Then clic on "Change permissions", select the user you added/edited, and then check the option called "Replace all child object permissions with inheritable permissions from this object", then clic apply

Comment: I had to restart IIS service as well for the setting changes to take effect. My plain virtual directories were not accessible because of this error. Simply enabling anonymous authentication at `Default Web Site` level helped me get rid of this error. It didn't require adding any predefined username or password.

Comment: Thanks. What is a bummer is if one site on iis does an account other than Application pool identity it makes all the sites use that. I always thought authentication could be set per site not all the sites.

Comment: Where can I find the IIS menu so that I can change the authentication?

Answer (score 27):

Open Project properties by selecting project then go to

> View>Properties Windows

and make sure **Anonymous Authentication** is Enabled

[image]

Comment: Life saver, even on my old webform project

Comment: @Yiping glad to help you

Answer (score 11):

Same thing happen to me this morning, everything was working fine for weeks before. yes guess what. I change my windows PC user account password yesterday night.
(how stupid was I)

So easy fix:

IIS -> authentication -> Anonymous authentication -> edit and set the user and new PASSWORD.

Comment: I was about to lose my hope to solve this, thanks :)

Comment: Where can I find the IIS menu so that I can change the authentication?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, and spent quite a bit of time trying to track down the solution. I had Anonymous Authentication set up at two different levels with two different users. Make sure that you're not overwriting your set up at a lower level.

Comment: This was my issue, the top level was one user and a child level was a different user.  I set them to the same user and it began working.

Answer (score 0):

I had not checked the `Authorization` header was set correctly in my request. I actually had `Authentication` which is not right.. Make sure you check the initiator!