# Windows Authentication in Chrome when using iframe

Tags: asp.net, windows, google-chrome, iis, iframe

In my service I use iframe which open another page in different domain. This page on ASP.NET IIS and uses Windows Authentication. In Chrome 84 it's working fine, but when I update to Chrome 89 I have an error:

> HTTP Error 401.2 - Unauthorized You are not authorized to view this page due to invalid authentication headers.

There is no error when I open page directly.
With Anonymous Authentication all is good, but I need Windows Authentication.

What should I do?

Comment: You can refer to: https://forums.iis.net/t/1153827.aspx?HTTP+Error+401+2+Unauthorized+You+are+not+authorized+to+view+this+page+due+to+invalid+authentication+headers+

Answer (score -1):

You may refer [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21603513/http-error-401-2-unauthorized-you-are-not-authorized-to-view-this-page-due-to) and [this link](https://weblogs.asp.net/jeffwids/you-are-not-authorized-to-view-this-page-due-to-invalid-authentication-headers#:%7E:text=HTTP%20Error%20401.2%20%2D%20Unauthorized&text=Most%20likely%20causes%3A,does%20not%20support%20integrated%20authentication.) too

Basically, you'd need to enable Anonymous Authentication in IIS and maybe in your project settings as well.

Comment: No, I NEED windows authentication exactly, cause in the page displays some account information. If Anonymous is enabled there is no information.